# How to get Artifact from Azure Pipelines using Jenkins?

Tags: ios, azure, jenkins, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

The build is set up in Azure DevOps and works well.
[image]

How do I get this build using Jenkins now? From Azure to Jenkins and only the file itself! I get repo, commits, but the assembled build cannot be configured for downloading in Jenkins.